# jQuery check multiple elements if they have the same class

Tags: jquery

I have an html structure like the following:

```
<table class="assignments-table">
   <tr class="assignment-row">
      <td class="100175">100175</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="assignment-row">
      <td class="100175">100175</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="assignment-row">
      <td class="100175">100175</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="assignment-row">
      <td class="100176">100176</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="assignment-row">
      <td class="100177">100177</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to find all the td elements that have the same class (these being the td class="100175" on the above example. ) using jQuery.

My jQuery code so far looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".assignment-row td:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
        if( $(this).length > 1) {
            console.log('more than one elements with same class exist');    
            $(this).addClass('same'); 
            // do other stuff too           
        } else {
            console.log('no elements with the same class exist');                           
        }       
});
```

The above code fails the condition check and goes into the else.

I have also tried a modification to my jQuery:

```
$(".assignments-table tr").each(function() {
    var t = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)");    
    if($(t).length){
        console.log('more than one elements with same class exist'); 
        $(t).addClass('same');
        // do other stuff too              
    } else {
        console.log('no elements with same class exist')
    };
});
```

which is also wrong as it proceeds and adds class="same" to all the :nth-child(1)  elements even if they dont have the same class.

Important note: These numbers are produced dynamically so i cannot use any of these directly as a selector.

Where is my mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What is it you're actually trying to achieve? The `:nth-child` selector will only find a single element, so the `each()` and  `length > 1` check  doesn't seem to be of much use. If all you want to do is select elements by their class, why not just use `$('.100175')`?

Comment: I cant use a specific class like $('.100175') because these numbers are produced dynamically and i have many many rows. I thought that by going into $('.assignment-row td:nth-child(1)') with .each(), i iterate on the first td of every row, am i wrong?

Comment: Ok, but what is your code trying to do?

Comment: Well i want to 1) add the class "same" to all the tds that have the same class in order to apply some css and 2nd) i may want to use the .wrapAll() function to wrap all the tds with class "same" with another element.

Comment: 1) In this case loop through the `td` elements and add a class of `same` to all the elements with the same class. You could possibly use `nextAll()` for this if the duplicates are in order. 2) This is not possible as you're using a table. `td` elements have to be within a `tr`. You cannot wrap anything else around them

Comment: That is what i am trying to do but the code i posted does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsbtp24w/1/) with your code corrected. I think I did what you were trying to do.

Basically, for each row, I got the td `class`, and verified in table, through the parent(), to check if there were more rows with the same `class`.

The problems with your code are:

```
$(".assignment-row td:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
        if( $(this).length > 1) { // You were checking for the length of the current td instead of the length for td's with the same class
            console.log('more than one elements with same class exist');    
            $(this).addClass('same'); 
            // do other stuff too           
        } else {
            console.log('no elements with the same class exist');                           
        }       
});
```

and

```
$(".assignments-table tr").each(function() {
    var t = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)"); // Here you were getting the current td
    // You should be looking for the tds with the same class instead
    if($(t).length){ // And here you were checking for the length of the td, that will allways be 1
        console.log('more than one elements with same class exist'); 
        $(t).addClass('same');
        // do other stuff too              
    } else {
        console.log('no elements with same class exist')
    };
});
```

If you don't understand something of my explanation, please tell me!